# White spaces are required between publicId and systemId

Tags: java, dom, jquery, xml-parsing

I am trying to make a ajax call to other domain locally from my computer by writing some proxy code in jsp. And this is my jQuery AJAX code that is calling proxy.jsp page.

```
 var metadata = 'https://rest-search.host.com/machine/search/meta?id=';

var on_show_info= function() {

    var AjaxCall = data + current_doc_info.id;
    alert(AjaxCall);
                request_meta_info = $.ajax({
                url: "proxy.jsp?url=" + AjaxCall,
                type: 'GET',
                success: check,
                error: error
        });
    };
```

And my JSP file is:-

```
<%@ page language="java" import="org.w3c.dom.*,javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder,javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory,java.net.*,java.io.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%

String urlToQuery = request.getParameter("url");
System.out.println("rj   " +urlToQuery);
URL url = new URL(urlToQuery);
final String login ="user";
final String password ="pass";

Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication (login, password.toCharArray());
    }
});
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db =dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc=db.parse(urlToQuery);


NodeList nl= doc.getElementsByTagName("attr");
%>


<%= nl.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %>
```

And When I check the response, I am getting this error for the XML file it is parsing:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /proxy.jsp. Reason:
<pre>    White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:180)
    at org.apache.jsp.proxy_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.proxy_jsp:70)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:67)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:122)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:110)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:536)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:915)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:539)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
</pre>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                
</body>
</html>
```

And the XMl file is this:-

```
<results><result><attr value="HW/SW" name="Line"/><attr value="ASIC" name="Description"/><attr value="CD" name="Number"/><attr value="AS" name="DocumentType"/><attr value="" name="Date"/><</result></results>
```

What wrong I am doing here.. Any suggestions will be appreciated..

Comment: even invalid pwd also can trigger this same error!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The error message is actually correct if not obvious. It says that your DOCTYPE must have a SYSTEM identifier. I assume yours only has a public identifier.

You'll get the error with (for instance):

```
<!DOCTYPE persistence PUBLIC
    "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
```

You won't with:

```
<!DOCTYPE persistence PUBLIC
    "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" "">
```

Notice `""` at the end in the second one -- that's the system identifier. The error message is confusing: it should say that you need a system identifier, not that you need a space between the publicId and the (non-existent) systemId.

By the way, an empty system identifier might not be ideal, but it might be enough to get you moving.

Answer (score 5):

I just found my self with this Exception, I was trying to consume a JAX-WS, with a custom URL like this:

```
String WSDL_URL= <get value from properties file>;
Customer service = new Customer(new URL(WSDL_URL));
ExecutePtt port = service.getExecutePt();
return port.createMantainCustomers(part);
```

and Java threw:

```
XML reader error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,63]
Message: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
```

Turns out that the URL string used to construct the service was missing the "?wsdl" at the end.
For instance:

Bad:

```
http://www.host.org/service/Customer
```

Good:

```
http://www.host.org/service/Customer?wsdl
```

Comment: Thanks. that's the problem I had to create a web service client on Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this post: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?68949-White-spaces-are-required-between-publicId-and-systemId./page2&s=c69fe19798f5a071d22eaf681ca84a56

A couple people here had success by switching the lines around in an XML file.

Comment: thanks for the response.. I cannot edit that xml file.. as that xml file is coming from apache solr.. So I have no control over that..And also that code is working fine for this xml `http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml`

Comment: The problem identified in the link is actually a correct solution to some scenarios. For xsi:schemaLocation value, each namespace must be followed by the schema location and not another namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of statments. 
For me, changing the block of code

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
```

with

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
```

is valid.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be related to the mistake of the person who opened the title, but I wanted to share it because it is the same error as the title.

It was an error I got in one of my runs jsf primeface on glassfish server with netbeans and maven.

This was the way of give me fail:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

But I returned this way and I didn't get any error:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working from some network that requires you to use a proxy in your browser to connect to the internet (likely an office building), that might be it.  I had the same issue and adding the proxy configs to the network settings solved it.

- Go to your preferences (Eclipse -> Preferences on a Mac, or Window -> Preferences on a Windows)
- Then -> General -> expand to view the list underneath -> Select Network Connections (don't expand)
- At the top of the page that appears there is a drop down, select "Manual."
- Then select "HTTP" in the list directly below the drop down (which now should have all it's options checked) and then click the "Edit" button to the right of the list.
- Enter in the proxy url and port you need to connect to the internet in your web browser normally.
- Repeat for "HTTPS."

If you don't know the proxy url and port, talk to your network admin.