# White spaces are required

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am getting the following error while parsing XML.

```
[Fatal Error] :1:63: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId
```

The XML is using web service.

Comment: Please post the XML. Sounds like it's probably broken...

Comment: Are there any white spaces between publicId and systemId?

Comment: Maybe you can put white space and try?  On a serious note, refer to [this related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514158/white-spaces-are-required-between-publicid-and-systemid).

Comment: *"Please guide."*  Please ask question (after editing the XML into the post).

Comment: I would imagine that the error message means exactly what it says.

Answer (score 2):

The order should be the follow: `interpretation category` then `interpretation file`.

- http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

Answer (score 1):

Basically the error says that your `DOCTYPE` must have a `SYSTEM` identifier in the wsdl file

Comment: this was working fine till last 2-3 days before. its showing white spare is required between publicId & systemId of InputSource object.

Comment: refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514158/white-spaces-are-required-between-publicid-and-systemid

Comment: In the WSDL data that I have seen, it typically does not have a DOCTYPE element.