# Errors occurring during build in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

Since yesterday, I have been receiving an error every time I try to run a program in Eclipse.  Pretty much I will edit pieces of my code and then will click the run button, which will give me the error.  After I click OK and try to run again, it will work.  The problem is this is happening every time I try to run after modifying code and is getting very annoying.  It does not matter which project I am working on in my workspace, it happens in all of them.

When in my project, the main class is called TSTMain.  The error I am getting is:

> 'Launching TSTMain' has encountered a problem.
>   Errors occurred during the build.

And clicking the details button brings up:

> Errors occurred during the build. 
>   Errors running builder 'Checkstyle Builder' on project 'TwitterSmileTracker'. 
>   unable to parse configuration stream - White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.:1:50 
>   unable to parse configuration stream - White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.:1:50 
>   unable to parse configuration stream - White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.:1:50 
>   unable to parse configuration stream - White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.:1:50

Obviously, it has something to do with Checkstyle.  I am unsure why this began just yesterday.  I uninstalled Checkstyle and reinstalled it but the problem still occurs.  If anyone has any suggestions on how I could make this stop, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Probably the checkstyle configuration is corrupted. You may configure checkstyle either on project-level or on workspace-level, so you should check both (maybe try a new, fresh config-file).

Comment: You can simple remove the checkstyle builder in the project properties. How did it get there? Is this a maven project or did you get a .project file from source checkout?

Comment: @eckes My university classes had us download checkstyle to use in eclipse for our projects.  I would remove it but I find it pretty useful in my code.  I am not using any dependency manager or build system.

Comment: According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6514158/1005481), the error could be in the `DOCTYPE` element of your *checkstyle.xml*. Can you show us the first few lines of your Checkstyle config file?