# Disabling XML validation in WebHarvest

Tags: xml-parsing, xsd, webharvest

I have a mobile application already published in the Apple's app store.

This SPI client app uses a Rest API in the server side to retrieve real time information regarding buses arrivals in a specific bus stop.

The app was working like a charm for 6 months.

The Rest API uses WebHarvest to scrap the real data information from a website (for instance: http://www.metlink.org.nz/stop/4912/departures).

Few days ago the HTML page scraped from my server side code has changed by adding the following line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

Since than, my app has stopped working.

I know I can strip the line above using regExp but I would like to know if there is a way to inform WebHarvest to disable the XML validation. Disabling XML validation, I don't need to go in every configuration that I have and change my xpath expression to a regExp to strip the line above.

Here is my configuration file:

```
<config charset="UTF-8">

    <var-def name="pageContentStr">
        <html-to-xml>
            <http url="http://www.metlink.org.nz/stop/${stationID.toString()}/departures" />
        </html-to-xml>
    </var-def>

    <var-def name="serverTime">
        <xpath expression="/html/body/ul/li/span/text()">
            <var name="pageContentStr" />
        </xpath>
    </var-def>

    <var-def name="busRTI">
            <xpath expression="//tbody/tr[@data-code]/concat(td[1]/a[starts-with(@href,'timetables/')]/span/text(),'::',td[1]/a[starts-with(@href,'timetables/bus/')]/span/attribute::style,'::',td[2]/span/text(),'::',td[3]/span/text())">
                <var name="pageContentStr" />
            </xpath>
    </var-def>
</config>
```

The config file inserted above is working fine if I run it inside WebHarvest GUI (weird). However, I receive an error when running it inside my Rest API. Here is the error that I receive:

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.webharvest.exception.ScraperXPathException: Error parsing XPath expression (XPath = [/html/body/ul/li/span/text()])!
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

org.webharvest.exception.ScraperXPathException: Error parsing XPath expression (XPath = [/html/body/ul/li/span/text()])!
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.XPathProcessor.execute(XPathProcessor.java:70)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:115)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BodyProcessor.execute(BodyProcessor.java:25)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.VarDefProcessor.execute(VarDefProcessor.java:59)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:115)
    org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper.execute(Scraper.java:166)
    org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper.execute(Scraper.java:179)
    com.didibaba.services.adapters.metlink.MetLinkAdapterImpl.scrapeBusesForStation(MetLinkAdapterImpl.java:147)
    com.didibaba.services.adapters.metlink.MetLinkAdapterImpl.getStationBuses(MetLinkAdapterImpl.java:118)
    com.didibaba.services.BusStationServiceImpl.getBusStationInfoByName(BusStationServiceImpl.java:80)
    com.didibaba.web.controllers.BusStationController.getBusStationInfo(BusStationController.java:36)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN; systemId: `http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd`; lineNumber: 31; columnNumber: 3; The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must end with '>'.
    net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:420)
    net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:169)
    net.sf.saxon.Configuration.buildDocument(Configuration.java:3346)
    net.sf.saxon.Configuration.buildDocument(Configuration.java:3288)
    net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.buildDocument(StaticQueryContext.java:327)
    org.webharvest.utils.XmlUtil.evaluateXPath(XmlUtil.java:77)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.XPathProcessor.execute(XPathProcessor.java:68)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:115)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BodyProcessor.execute(BodyProcessor.java:25)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.VarDefProcessor.execute(VarDefProcessor.java:59)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:115)
    org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper.execute(Scraper.java:166)
    org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper.execute(Scraper.java:179)
    com.didibaba.services.adapters.metlink.MetLinkAdapterImpl.scrapeBusesForStation(MetLinkAdapterImpl.java:147)
    com.didibaba.services.adapters.metlink.MetLinkAdapterImpl.getStationBuses(MetLinkAdapterImpl.java:118)
    com.didibaba.services.BusStationServiceImpl.getBusStationInfoByName(BusStationServiceImpl.java:80)
    com.didibaba.web.controllers.BusStationController.getBusStationInfo(BusStationController.java:36)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN; systemId: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd; lineNumber: 31; columnNumber: 3; The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must end with '>'.
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1388)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanEntityDecl(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:1562)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDecls(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:1964)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDTDExternalSubset(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:297)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1162)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1049)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:962)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:396)
    net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:169)
    net.sf.saxon.Configuration.buildDocument(Configuration.java:3346)
    net.sf.saxon.Configuration.buildDocument(Configuration.java:3288)
    net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.buildDocument(StaticQueryContext.java:327)
    org.webharvest.utils.XmlUtil.evaluateXPath(XmlUtil.java:77)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.XPathProcessor.execute(XPathProcessor.java:68)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:115)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BodyProcessor.execute(BodyProcessor.java:25)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.VarDefProcessor.execute(VarDefProcessor.java:59)
    org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:115)
    org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper.execute(Scraper.java:166)
    org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper.execute(Scraper.java:179)
    com.didibaba.services.adapters.metlink.MetLinkAdapterImpl.scrapeBusesForStation(MetLinkAdapterImpl.java:147)
    com.didibaba.services.adapters.metlink.MetLinkAdapterImpl.getStationBuses(MetLinkAdapterImpl.java:118)
    com.didibaba.services.BusStationServiceImpl.getBusStationInfoByName(BusStationServiceImpl.java:80)
    com.didibaba.web.controllers.BusStationController.getBusStationInfo(BusStationController.java:36)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a `omithtmlenvelope="true"` in your [html-to-xml](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/manual.php#html-to-xml) call.

```
<var-def name="pageContentStr">
    <html-to-xml omithtmlenvelope="true">
        <http url="http://www.metlink.org.nz/stop/${stationID.toString()}/departures" />
    </html-to-xml>
</var-def>
```

However, unfortunately, as you said I cannot reproduce the error you are getting, and cannot test the result...

Comment: Yuo can test it actually. Get my config file and run using WebHarvest GUI. We are able to see the values for each var. However, if I put the omithtmlenvelope=true option no values are retrieved. Anyway, Thanks trying to help me

Comment: can you confirm which version of the webharvest you are running? 1.0, 2.0, 2.1? And by "I cannot recreate your error" I mean that I can run your script, exactly as you posted here in WH 2.0 GUI, and it runs through ok, and populates variables as expected.

Comment: In my app I am using WebHarvest 2.1.0-RC1. It was working few days ago. As I mentioned to you if I run using the GUI, as soon as WebHarvest transforms from HTML to XML, it strips the DOCTYPE line from the xml. Inside my server the DOCTYPE remains there. I was wondering probably there is some settings to say to WebHarvest to either ignore that line or disable XML validation.

Comment: When I say "it didn't work" means it didn't solve my problem. omithtmlenvelope="true" stripped the DOCTYPE, but also removed the HTML and BODY tags. So now I don't have a root element and xpath says me the following message: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: When I run your script in the GUI, or in headless I dont get any errors. This suggests to me that either: the response your server gets from "metlink" is different than what we see on the desktop because of proxies, IP filtering, blocking etc. OR you are using different version of webharvest/java on your machine and on the server OR the script you run on the server is not identical to what you have posted here.

Comment: Anyhow: the only further advice I can offer is to use webharvest debugging to save intermediate results (such as output from http, html-to-xml and var-def processors), and scrutinise them after the error occurs.

Comment: Let me try to put my problem in a different way:

Comment: I've came accross a bug... well not exactly a bug per se, but a non working feature :
When you try to webharvest a webpage starting with a classic <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> (like any Facebook page for instance) doctype header, you get an exception !
According to this page (http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic)

Comment: the problem seems to be that the parser automatically tries to download the DTD "xhtml1-strict.dtd" from the W3 website, due to the !DOCTYPE directive in the webpage.
I've been unable to find a way to bypass this limitation, but I would be definitely like to see that corrected ! If not, this great tool fall useless for a lot of websites, and that would be a shame !

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with the xpath evaluator throwing an `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException`

`White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.`

When you can change the origin xml, the solution for this problem is already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514158/white-spaces-are-required-between-publicid-and-systemid).

Webharvest uses [html cleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) under the hood. I use the Complete Web-Harvest project and so could prevent adding the doctype-tag on the `html-to-xml`.

I use html cleaner version 2.6.1., and modified `org.webharvest.runtime.processors.HtmlToXmlProcessor` to support this newer version

```
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner( );
CleanerProperties cleanerProperties = cleaner.getProperties();
```

As html cleaner supports an [omitDoctypeDeclaration - parameter](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/parameters.php) ommiting the doctype at all, I added that (in future that might be done via an extra attribute with the scraper xml).

```
cleanerProperties.setOmitDoctypeDeclaration(true);
```

Hope it helps, and thanks to the creator of webharvest, it is a great and pretty reliable tool!