# White spaces are required between publicId and systemId

Tags: java, xml

Dom parser give below exception while parsing xml file in which public id exist but system id does not exist.
For example:

> <!DOCTYPE SPIN PUBLIC "-//AIP//DTD aipspin//EN">  <root> ...   </root>
>
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: White spaces are required between
>   publicId and systemId. at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:249)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
>         at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:180)
>         at com.main.parse.main(parse.java:77)

One way to resolve is to change add dummy system id along with space,  but I cannot do manual changes in xml file.
Is there any way that we can adjust through code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [White spaces are required between publicId and systemId](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514158/white-spaces-are-required-between-publicid-and-systemid)

Comment: Is there any body who can help me on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You may be behind your company's proxy and you network may not be able to parse the url of the xsd file.

To resolve you may try the following-
Replace URL of xsd or xml file with classpath's version.

Example:

Replace
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
with
classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd

Worked for me..

Comment: Thanks for solution. But the problem i cannot edit the file manually therefore i need to go through the code and resolve the problem.