# DOCTYPE declaration is missing the system identifier

Tags: html, doctype

I'm receiving the following response from a web server.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Service Unavailable</TITLE> <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD> <BODY><h2>Service Unavailable</h2> <hr><p>HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.</p> </BODY></HTML>
```

I'm a bit confused as to whether or not this html is valid.

When I try to parse the document in my code I get a `White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.` which indicates that the DOCTYPE declaration is missing the system identifier. But then when I go to the W3C validator it seems to pass validation.

Is it valid HTML?

Comment: It's valid. Why do you want to parse a 503 error page? Wouldn't it be easier to check the HTTP status code you got when downloading that page?

Comment: thanks @helb, Yes I agree I should be checking the error code however in this scenario I'm more interested in learning about the error being returned by my parser and why it is returning that error because in theory if the document in valid it should parse right? So take this more as an understanding exercise.

Comment: Your parser probably doesn't like the doctype, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9225499/3776299